# How can I tell drush to use another php.ini file?

Tags: drush

I've gone through the setup instructions on https://github.com/drush-ops/drush, but I can't seem to get drush to use a different configuration file, very frustrating.

I've already added the PHP_INI environment variable to my .bashrc and sourced it, seems like there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Did you try `echo $PHP_INI` to make sure that the environment variable is really set?

Answer (score 3):

I copied my php.ini file to my home directory, and then ran:

```
$ PHP_INI=~/php.ini drush status
```

The "PHP configuration" line accurately reflected the new location of my php.ini file, so I believe this is still working on Drush 6.x and master.

Comment: i'll just add where to copy the php.ini `cp /etc/php5/cli/php.ini ~/.drush/`

Comment: For some reason, echo $PHP_INI does not return the value, despite having `export PHP_INI="/private/etc/php.ini"` in my .bashrc.

Comment: Type `source ~/.bashrc` from your terminal to re-execute your .bashrc.  Editing this file does nothing until you source it, or start a new terminal session.

Comment: using `export PHP_INI="/private/etc/php-cli.ini"` in ~/.bashrc to run a different ini file from command line drush worked great on CentOS and PHP7.1

Answer (score 3):

drush uses PHP CLI which has it's own `php.ini` file

e.g, in ubuntu:

```
/etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

You can use that.